# Is it possible to output on multiple terminal windows within a single C program?

Tags: c, stdio, terminal

Basically what I'd like to do is have two output terminal windows for a single program. One would be displaying a log of actions being taken by the program, and the second would be displaying something like a table of values. All of the output for these terminals would be generated by the program itself. Is this possible to do in C with stdio?

I realise this is probably something more suited for a GUI or ncurses, but I'm still curious as to whether this can be done regardless.

Edit: Should probably also mention I'm doing this on linux (xubuntu specifically).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in any portable way, but on Linux, `/dev/pts` is a directory containing all of the open ttys, so writing to a few diferent `/dev/pts/<n>` files would put output on multiple terminals.