# How to output in multiple terminal windows with a c program

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a simple chat-room application in c using posix sockets.
However I'll have this issue in sending messages.

```
(client1)say something: Hello folks! what are 

client2 said: xyzabc

client3 said: dsgh
```

Here above is the client1's terminal window where he was trying to send *"Hello folks! what are you doing?"* but before he could write his messsage and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, client2 and client3 sent something.(separate thread for receiving messages)

I'm trying to tackle this issue by using 2 different terminal windows for each client, one for writing the message and another for displaying the chat messages.

To begin with I've opened a gnome-terminal window by writing

```
system("gnome-terminal");
```

but now,

I want to perform some read write operations on the terminal window I've opened and the existing window.

```
printf("This is existing window"); //want to print this on existing terminal

printf("this is new terminal window"); //want to print this on new terminal

scanf("%d",&a); //take input from existing window

scanf("%d",&b); //take input from new window
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803327/is-it-possible-to-output-on-multiple-terminal-windows-within-a-single-c-program) that I can do it by reading/writing from proper `/dev/pts/<n>` file.
But how do I find the n in the `/dev/pts/<n>` for the current terminal and the new terminal window I just opened? Is there any better way of solving the issue?

Comment: Look into terminal libraries, such as ncurses. They allow you to have multiple "windows" within a single terminal, which can fix your issue, but require a different io pattern than simple printf/scanf functions.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287725) can help

Comment: @Smith_61 I've used curses  once before but I don't know how to open multiple windows with it. Can you be a little bit more specific as to which curses function should I use?

Comment: @ARBY I should have been more specific. Ncurses doesn't contain the ability to open multiple terminals, at least not that I know of. Instead it allows you to have much more control over where output is written into the terminal buffer. Allowing you to emulate different "sub-windows" in a single terminal instance.

Comment: @Smith_61 Sounds legit. Thanks. I'm reading more about it.

Comment: @XYZProgrammer, There also the issue remains unsolved. All they have done is suggested to write a different program that sends back the output of  `tty`

Answer (score 2):

One known good way is using the [alternate interface](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html) to GNU Readline:

> Some applications need to interleave keyboard I/O with file, device, or window system I/O, typically by using a main loop to select() on various file descriptors. To accomodate this need, readline can also be invoked as a `callback' function from an event loop.

The pseudocode skeleton is as follows:

```
  rl_callback_handler_install (prompt, my_handler)

  while true
     wait on stdin and socket (select or poll)
     if stdin is ready            
        rl_callback_read_char();
     if socket is ready
        read message from socket
        save readline state
        print message
        restore readline state

   void my_handler(char* line)            
        send line to socket
```

Saving and restoring readline state is

```
  saved_line = rl_copy_text(0, rl_end);
  rl_save_prompt();
  rl_replace_line("", 0);
  rl_redisplay();

  rl_restore_prompt();
  rl_replace_line(saved_line, 0);
  rl_point = saved_point;
  rl_redisplay();
  free(saved_line);
```

A complete, if rudimentary, chat program that utilises this method can bee found [here](https://gist.github.com/en-em/e8889248644723b0fc28ce2dd5d50701).

Comment: I took the liberty of copying a smalll snippet of that page to show *why* this is a good solution. (Nice, by the way. I'm trying to get used to use `readline` in favour of `fgets`, and this is a handy addition!)

Comment: I've never used `readline` before. If that will do the job, I'll read it first. Will accept the solution after I've read it. Thank you.